# Method invocation 'setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

Why this line produce NullPointerException?

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I have imported android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
in build.grade I am using com.android.support.design:25.0.1

```
public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_activity);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // finish the activity
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Errors: http://pastebin.com/aCQ4Hvpi

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This conditional will fix that warning:

`if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {`

This is how I have my SupportActionBar set up, maybe this will help!

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: This solved my problem: if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }

Comment: @Defus , whenever you see such a warning (it is not an error), it means you should have a mechanism to null check. It is a lint warning.

Comment: But it maked that app crashed

Comment: @RowlandMtetezi that's not a simple warning, you have to take an action. Actually, in some cases `getSupportActionBar()` returns `null`. So `null` check is important